# Deleting Rows by condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is the image that describes my data frame, I wish to conditionally delete all city names which have "Range" written in them as indicated in the snippet. I tried various approaches but haven't been successful so far. 
[image]

Comment: Some code to generate data would be much more useful than a screenshot, it would help others help you. See http://reprex.tidyverse.org for how to make a reprex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` with invert option to select all lines without `Range`.

```
yourDataFrame <- yourDataFrame[grep("Range", yourDataFrame$City, invert = TRUE), ]
```

Comment: You'll have troubles if `grep` returns no matches (`integer(0)`).  `grepl` is safer.

Comment: Thank You so much for your solution, your solution solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two things: detect a pattern in a character vector, you can use `stringr::str_detect()` and extract a subset of rows, this is `dplyr::filter()` purpose.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
  filter( ! str_detect(City, "Range") )
```